# Trying to override icon_url in JSON payload Slack Webhook not working

Tags: laravel, notifications, webhooks, slack, slack-api

I use **Laravel 8.x** Slack Notifications.

```
return (new SlackMessage)
            ->from("customUsername")
            ->image('https://laravel.com/img/favicon/favicon.ico')
            ->content("customContent");
```

I also check the JSON payload returned by Laravel, it's correct with good parameters: icon_url, username and icon_emoji.

**My problem is that icon_url is not showing in Slack.**

I don't understand why custom username and icon_emoji are working properly, but icon_url not showing and so not overriding the default image configured in the Webhook app.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe ico isn't an acceptable format

Comment: Thanks, but also try with others formats (jpg, png), not working also. 
And this image URL is the one of available Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#customizing-the-sender-recipient